# AS3: TextField seems to have an invisible background fill?

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, textfield

Let's get started.

I create a Sprite 'father', add another Sprite 'child' as it child, and draw a filled rectangle with the graphics property of the 'child' Sprite. Then, I add another TextField instance as a child of the 'father' Sprite, and set its text to, say, "Payphone", in such a way that the text is displayed on the filled rectangle.

At last I add an event listener, listening to MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, that traces "HIT!", when I move the mouse on the edges of the filled rectangle, it traces "HIT!"; but when I move the mouse around the center of the filled rectangle it doesn't trace anything. And mentioning that my mouse was in the bounding box of the TextField, does TextField have an invisible background fill? Is it able to be removed? How?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, a `TextField`'s hit area is always its bounding box, even if you set its `background` property to `false`. However, you can still disable a TextField from intercepting your parent object's mouse events be setting its `mouseEnabled` property to `false`. You can also make the parent object receive all of its children's mouse events by setting the parent's `mouseChildren` property to `false`.

However, both of these solutions will disable all mouse events on your text field, so if that is a requirement for whatever reason, you'll have to look for a more complex solution.

Comment: Great, thank you! I just need the mouse events to work on the 'child' sprite that lies under the TextField. :)

Comment: You could use the text itself as the hit area (rather than the bounding box), if you apply the TextField as a mask object to another solid sprite.  That sprite's hit area will then use the shapes of the characters in the text field, since a sprite's hit area includes any pixel which is not fully transparent.